# What is replacement of font MTLmr3m.ttf in Android M

Tags: android, fonts, android-6.0-marshmallow

I was trying to figure out what system font we can use in android M as a replacement of MTLmr3m.ttf as Google has removed this font in sdk 23 and because which my app couldn't show Japanese characters.

EDIT:
I don't want to bundle any font to my apk as this will lead to increase in size, I want is there any replacement font present in Android-M which I can use to render Japanese characters.

Any help and any way to get out of this situation will be appreciated.
Edits are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not download the raw file and package it in your app, referencing it from there as oppose to from the frameworks?

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/21e6e2de1f0062f949fcc52d0b4559dfa3246e0e/data/fonts/MTLmr3m.ttf

Comment: it will increase my apk size that's why I don't want to bundle this font, asking for any other font which could replace it and present in the system. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try NotoSansJP-Regular.otf

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: I tried but it was too not working :(, I want to render Japanese pdf for that I want font.